Gamma distribution: why do dgamma and rgamma give different results
x <- seq(0.00001, 0.0008,0.000001)
a = 2
b = 0.000187
set.seed(123) 
plot(x,dgamma(x, shape = a, scale =b), 
   type="l", lwd=2, ylab="Density", 
   xlab="probability of infection")

sample_size <- 10000
set.seed(123)
v <- rgamma(sample_size, shape = a, scale = b)
summary(v)
hist(v)

I am running this code to get a density plot of the gamma distribution; however, I have noticed when I later run a rgamma using the same values, the distribution looks wildly different and the average of the graph is dramatically off. Can anyone help me see why this is generating such different values?

histogram settings: hist(v, breaks=100, freq = FALSE); lines(x,dgamma(x, shape = a, scale =b), col="red", lwd=3) (or could plot the density)

The Gamma density and the empiric distribution are not that different.
Note that I have extended the vector x.
x <- seq(0.00001, 0.002,0.000001)
a <- 2
b <- 0.000187

sample_size <- 10000
set.seed(123)

v <- rgamma(sample_size, shape = a, scale = b)
y <- dgamma(x, shape = a, scale = b)

hist(v, ylim = c(0, max(y)), freq = FALSE, ylab = "Density", xlab = "probability of infection")
lines(x, y, lwd = 2)


Created on 2024-11-03 with reprex v2.1.1

Edit
Note also that you can fit a gamma to the empiric density values and compare the results with the parameters you have defined above. Once again, the results are not that different.
(The shape parameter returned by fitdistrplus::fitdist is the inverse of R's parametrization.)
h <- hist(v, plot = FALSE)
p <- fitdistrplus::fitdist(h$density, "gamma", "mme")
p
#> Fitting of the distribution ' gamma ' by matching moments 
#> Parameters:
#>          estimate  Std. Error
#> shape 0.484456954 1.199296039
#> rate  0.001162697 0.003327934
1/p$estimate["shape"]
#>    shape 
#> 2.064167

Created on 2024-11-03 with reprex v2.1.1
